# Remotely whitelist SSH access to a specific IP Address

Tags: iptables, firewall

I just rented a server with a cloud provider that has no way of white listing SSH Access.
I'm trying to figure out a way to remotely whitelist my IP Address to have access to my server via SSH and blacklist everyone else. I was thinking about using IP tables, but this will never work as my IP Address is dynamic. Similar to AWS security groups. I am willing to use a paid services as long as it's not expensive or even better if someone knows of a service or an efficient way where I can remotely manage iptables in case of ip change/lockout.

Comment: I understand the peace of mind that comes from limiting access to just one IP address. But this isn't obviously more secure than just public key authentication, and it carries an additional risk of locking you out if your script fails for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather simple to use a script to update iptables and a DDNS service.

Put the IP action in a separate chain:

```
-A MYIP -s 1.2.3.4/32 -j ACCEPT
-A MYIP -j DROP
```

and then run this chain on your SSH port, e.g.

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j MYIP
```

Then periodically (e.g. `cron`) run a script that does a `nslookup` on the dynamic IP and flushes/rewrites the `MYIP` chain if a change is detected.

```
#!/bin/bash

IPSAVE=/etc/sysconfig/iptables

update_iptables() {
  MN=$1
  CHAIN=$2

  IP=`nslookup ${MN} | tail --lines=-3 | grep Address | awk '{print $2}'`
  if [ `echo ${IP} | wc -m` -gt 0 ]
  then
    C=`grep -c "\-A ${CHAIN} \-j " ${IPSAVE}`
    D=`grep "\-A ${CHAIN} \-s " ${IPSAVE} | grep -c "${IP}"`
    if [ ${C} -gt 0 ] && [ ${D} -eq 0 ]
    then
      /sbin/iptables -F ${CHAIN}
      /sbin/iptables -A ${CHAIN} -s ${IP}/32 -j ACCEPT
      /sbin/iptables -A ${CHAIN} -j DROP
    fi
  fi
}

update_iptables my.dynamic.hostname.com MYIP
```